# Export a Classifier to Human-Readable File

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a task in NLP to train a classifier and export it to human-readable format. What is the best application to do so.

I tried to use NLTK, however it does not have an export capability  to human-readable format, for example

this is a classifier

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

and I need it to save and later use for my own needs without any connection to NLTK

I am aware about **pickle** trick, however it's not entire human-readable.

What is the best and comfortable tool to use for training classifier and export it to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xhudik is correct.  Bayes is going to be a black-box algorithm, but if I understand your intent correctly -- that you may want to understand the coefficients of certain words/feature inputs, why not just walk through the model? Even using Naive Bayes you can check the likelihood values the classifier outputs and just serialize those to a file.

Example:  you have 3 classes: A, B and C

```
        A     B      C
n1 ->  .2    .6     .2
n2 ->  .5    .1     .4
.
.
.
```

[read more here](http://nltk.org/book/ch06.html#fig-naive-bayes-triangle)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not really understand what you are trying to do. If I understood correctly - you would like to see **how precisely is your trained model/classifier working**.

In this case, you shouldn't care what type of SW package you use, but what algorithm is deployed instead. That means you should not use so-called **black-box** algorithms like, for example, neural networks, Bayes,... Try to use decision trees (e.g. J48) instead - it will give you a guide (human-readable) knowledge how it is working.

Comment: Naive Bayes is as far from "black-box" as any regression. It is eminently interpretable!